# What exactly is Unity?

Tags: unity

I still do not understand about Unity, please help me
is it same with Docky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity is a replacement for Gnome panel (or Gnome Shell or others), wich are the interfaces seen by the user when he start a session. For example, gnome panel, is actually used by Ubuntu in its desktop version. It's the two panels (top and bottom and top) that you see when you open a session, includung the desktop. 
Unity consist of the dock on the right, the menu bar on the top, the applications and files menus....(http://www.google.com/images?um=1&hl=fr&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=ubuntu+unity&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) : Unity is the whole interface of Ubuntu netbook ( and in 11.04 version, of Desktop version too). 
But beware, Unity doesn't replace Gnome, it just replace the gnome interface. Unity still use most parts of the Gnome project (for the backend, the aplications...)

Answer (score 2):

I recently saw about this excellent post [Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat Netbook Edition (Unity)](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat-has-been.html) with a lot of graphics and comments.

However, if you are looking for a press release, look at this [Canonical page](http://www.canonical.com/engineering-services/oem-services/why-ubuntu/products). And for more technical details, look at this [Mark's post](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/383) or visit the [project page](http://unity.ubuntu.com/). Thanks!

Comment: I can see here, Unity is the new brand UI for Ubuntu Netbook.

Comment: for my netbook, I used Jolicloud because Ubuntu Netbook Edition cannot connect to neither wireless neither mobile broadband but only worked with Ethernet. from the not friendly & not ubiquitous of it, I have no confidence of using UNE since then

Comment: @ok comp: The next version of Unity (in 11.04) is planned to use NetworkManager just like the standard Ubuntu does, so that problem should be gone then (if everything goes according to the planning).